# Linearly independent vectors coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the set $\{\vec u_1, \vec u_2, \ldots \vec u_n\}$ is linearly independent and that $\vec w$ is a linear combination of these vectors. Is it true that the coefficients of the linear combination are unique? How so?

I do not understand how to prove that the coefficients are unique.

Comment: Can you clarify? If $a u_1 + b u_2 = c u_3$, then $-a u_1  -b u_2 = -c u_3$.

Comment: If you have $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n$ are linearly **dependent** then you have some choice of $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ such that $c_1u_1+c_2u_2+\dots+c_nu_n = 0$ where at least one of the $c_i$ are nonzero.  This is by the very definition of what it means to be linearly independent.  If you are asking whether if some vector $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $u_i$ whether the coefficients are unique, certainly not.  Just add zero to it in the form guaranteed to exist as described above to change the coefficients.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Sorry I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Your edit changed the word to **independent** in the body.  In this case, the answer is absolutely yes.  Suppose that there were two different representations.  Subtract the one from the other.  Since they are both equal to $w$, you have this must be zero, but that would be a contradiction as you cannot express zero as a linear combination of these without using all coefficients equal to zero, again by the very definition of what it means to be linearly independent.

Comment: @JMoravitz But what does it mean that the coefficients are unique?

Comment: That if $v= a_1u_1+a_2u_2+\dots+a_nu_n$ and $v=b_1u_1+b_2u_2+\dots+b_nu_n$ then you must have $a_i=b_i$ for every $i$.  That is to say, there is one and only one way to express a vector from the span as a linear combination from that span.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, thanks a lot, now I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that if the $u_i$ are linearly *independent* then every vector can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the $u_i$. Suppose
$$a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + \cdots + a_nu_n = b_1u_1 + b_2u_2 + \cdots + b_nu_n.$$
Then
$$(a_1 - b_1)u_1 + (a_2 - b_2)u_2 + \cdots + (a_n - b_n)u_n = 0.$$
Since the $u_i$ are linearly independent we conclude $a_i - b_i = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

$w=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k$ where $v_1,...,v_n$ is a set of linearly independent vectors and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are its correcponding coefficients.

We will prove this statement using proof by contradiction.

We start by assuming that the choice of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is not unique. i.e.

$w=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_kv_k$ where at least one $\alpha_k\neq\beta_k$

Here,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_kv_k\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\alpha_kv_k+\alpha_nv_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\beta_kv_k+\beta_nv_n\\
v_n=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\beta_kv_k-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\alpha_kv_k}{\alpha_n-\beta_n}$

However, this contradicts our assumption that the vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly independent.

So, our assumption that the choice of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is not unique is false.
So, the choice of $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ is unique.